# add conditional properties to typescript interface if property has a certain value

Tags: typescript

How can I add additional properties to an interface, if another property has a certain value? For example:

```
interface IBaseColumn {
  name: string
  display?: boolean
}

interface ISpecialColumn extends IBaseColumn {
  name: 'SpecialColumn'
  extraProp?: any
}

export type IColumn = IBaseColumn | ISpecialColumn

// ...
const columns: IColumn[] = [/* ... */]

const column = columns.find(c => c.name === 'SpecialColumn') // IColumn | undefined
```

I want `IBaseColumn` to have additional properties, if the name is `SpecialColumn`. The example above works, but since `columns` is of type `IColumn[]`, so is the column I look up with `.find`. The only workaround I found was to cast column to `ISpecialColumn`, but ideally the type would be infered correctly automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *type guard*:

```
const isSpecialClumn = (column: IColumn): column is ISpecialColumn =>
  column.name === 'SpecialColumn'

const column = columns.find(isSpecialClumn) // ISpecialColumn | undefined
```